# PHP is not detected in PHP Interpreters, PhpStorm 2020.3, Laravel 8

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, laravel-8

## What I am trying to do:

I am trying to run/debug unit tests within PhpStorm 2020.3, on Laravel 8. The ENV is WSL 2 on Windows 10.

## Problem(s)

**One:** PHP and Xdebug is not detected when I select the service in CLI interpreters.
[image]

**Two:** When I run/debug unit tests, I get different errors, one of which:

```
[docker-compose://[\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\musa\codes\boom\finance\docker-compose.yml]:laravel.test/]:php /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php --configuration /var/www/html/phpunit.xml
Testing started at 8:31 PM ...
Version mismatch: file \\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\musa\codes\xyz\docker-compose.yml specifies version 3.9 but extension file C:\Users\musah\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm2020.3\tmp\docker-compose.override.9.yml uses version 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I suppose the 2nd problem will be fixed if I can fix the first one.

## Details:

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  laravel.test:
    build:
      context: ./docker/development
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP:-wwwdata}'
    image: sail-8.0/app
    ports:
      - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
      - '9003:9003'
    environment:
      WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER:-wwwdata}'
      LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/www/html'
      - './docker/development/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-ext-xdebug.ini'
      - './docker/development/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/99-sail.ini'
      - './docker/development/http.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf'
      - './docker/development/supervisord.conf:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf'
    networks:
      - sail
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
      - selenium
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./docker/development/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
      MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - sail
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
      - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'sailredis:/data'
    networks:
      - sail
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]

  mailhog:
    image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
    ports:
      - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
      - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
    networks:
      - sail

  selenium:
    image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome:latest'
    volumes:
      - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
    networks:
      - sail

  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - SERVICES=lambda,s3
    ports:
      - '4566:4566'
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    networks:
      - sail

networks:
  sail:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  sailmysql:
    driver: local
  sailredis:
    driver: local
  sailmeilisearch:
    driver: local
```

`docker/development/Dockerfile` file:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

ARG WWWGROUP

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl zip unzip supervisor libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/local/bin/php

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 9003

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

`docker/development/php.ini` file:

```
[PHP]
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
variables_order = EGPCS
```

`docker/development/xdebug.ini` file:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.log = "/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

`docker/development/supervisord.conf` file:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[program:php]
command=/usr/local/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
user=sail
environment=LARAVEL_SAIL="1"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

`docker/development/start-container` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ ! -z "$WWWUSER" ]; then
    usermod -u $WWWUSER sail
fi

if [ ! -d /.composer ]; then
    mkdir /.composer
fi

chmod -R ugo+rw /.composer

if [ $# -gt 0 ];then
    exec gosu $WWWUSER "$@"
else
    /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my surprise both the problems were fixed by specifying the `version` in `docker-compose.yml` file as:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  laravel.test:
    build:
      context: ./docker/development
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
...
```

Reference: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38394